# SAS not updating code

Tags: sas

So I'm trying to code something in SAS however when I erase old code, save the new code, and run it the old code still performs even though it doesn't even show up in the code or log sheet.

I'll post some screen shots so you understand.

You'll notice in the example that the title is included after I erased it from the code and ran it. Also the observations are starting at 3 rather than at 1.

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System options like TITLE and FIRSTOBS you probably used in old code persist in SAS session until changed. Try starting new session to see whether this is your case (I can't judge from what you provided).

Comment: That's almost certainly FIRSTOBS=3 given the output on the screen.

Comment: You can also reset a title by issuing `title;`